# Where do you have to position setcookie in php code?

Tags: php, mysql, setcookie

I am building a website where a user will enter data in a form, which will then be looked up in the database for other users that match the same criteria.

Where I am stuck is that I am trying to set up a second database that will store the search criteria they used plus some of their details. To be able to keep track of the line of data they added to the database I have included an ID to the database that will be auto incremented and would like to set this as a cookie.

In the code below, the $resultCheck is following a SELECT query that idetifies matching results.

Where should I be using setcookie in this example?

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO results (email, link, contactInfo, price) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['userEmail']."', '$link', '$contactInfo','$askPrice');";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    exit();
}   

else{               
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $email, $link, $contactInfo, $askPrice);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);             
}
$resultId = $row['resultId'];
setcookie("resulId", $resultId, 0, '/');
header("Location: ../results.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Anywhere before you output headers. Unless there is code you have not shown, this code should be fine as is.

Comment: It looks like you left out a chunk of code when posting. You exit immediately after initializing the statement, you never call `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`.

Comment: @JohnConde I think you mean before outputting content. It can be mixed in with other headers.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).